# maven package submodule and test the parent

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I am a maven newbie.
My test project depends on module project (extended-java-client).
I need to run "mvn clean package" on the module path which gives me extended-java-client-Jar.

Then, I need to run "mvn clean install test" to run the test project.
but it's not working, it didn't find the module.
(I already added the module/parent tags to pom.xml file)

Any idea?
Thanks in advance

This is the structure of my project:

```
Project A
  *Extended-java-client(Module)
      *pom.xml (jar file)
  *src(the test classes)
  *pom.xml
```

extended-> pom.xml

```
 <parent>
      <groupId>project name</groupId>
      <artifactId>project name</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath> // path to main pom
  </parent>
```

project-> pom.xml

```
<modules>
   <module>extended-java-client</module>
</modules>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you build `extended-java-client` you should use run `$ mvn clean install` instead of `$ mvn clean package`

The reason: `package` creates the jar but leaves it inside `extended-java-client/target/` directory so that the jar file is visible only to that one project.

Calling `install` copies the jar into what Maven calls the "local repo" so that other projects (such as your test project) can access it.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

What do you exactly mean by *"it's not working"?* Is there an error msg you can supply?

I'd recommend to use the [Standard Directory Layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html), especially when beginning with Maven.

However, you don't have to run `mvn clean install test`. The `test` phase is performed prior to the `install` phase (and also to the `package` phase) automatically.

See [Introduction to the Build Lifecycle, Default Lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Default_Lifecycle): *"These build phases [...] are executed sequentially to complete the default lifecycle."*

Comment: it's failed to run the tests. it's not recognize the classes's module.